# ThreeJS - project/raycast mouse click to XZ plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, raycasting

I'm trying to implement offline routing in 3D map inside ThreeJS scene. I want user to click a point and then navigate a cube to this point. Navigation works correctly but clicked point isn't accurate. Flat map is a plane in XZ coordinates with Y axis up. In the scene I've got Orbit Controls which when orbiting change the position argument of camera, thus raycasting is not accurate with the way I'm doing it. I need to get correct XZ coords in whatever orbit state. I'm getting correct coords for traditional raycasting in 3D but as I said this is not what I need. I tried basic method from ThreeJS docs for raycaster, answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973060/converting-2d-mouse-coordinates-to-world-xz-coordinates-in-threejs) and unprojecting mouse click with `Vector3.unproject()` without any success.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/e6b20xto/2/) is jsfiddle to illustrate what I mean. There are some important explanation comments.

Comment: When you do traditional ray cast I think you will get proper x y then you unprojet them to get 3d point in world space. Do you maintain any transformation matrix for orbit state?

Comment: I didn't use any matrix so maybe this is some clue. I know that in orbit controls offset vector with applied quaterion is added to target vector. This works fine for 3D coords but I can't then just choose x and z. I think I should apply apply some transformation there but I don't know what should it be / do.

Comment: You have quaternion and offset vector you can prepare transformation matrix using that I think.

Comment: But will I then have the correct coordinates? What I think is that I'll create matrix with "separates" accual position from rotation and then use it for math in unprojecting the mouse click? I will research it further later. I'm really just getting started in this topic, is this what I think right or I'm off the way totally?

Comment: I think there is some confusion.  By clicking in screen you get mouse position in 2d those are in screen space . By unprojet you are converting this screens pace to world space. When you orbit you do so in world space. For example I have point sx,sy,sz and I apply quaternion and offset on it to orbit but this all is happening in world space.  So I think if you build matrix of your orbit transformation you get generalised way to orbit any point if that point is in world space.  Hence first by unprojet you bring your 2d vertex in 3d world space and with orbit transform bring them in orbit space.

Comment: @ArekAreknawo it's better to show us some code, possibly with pictures, which will help to describe the problem. So far, we can only imagine and suggest what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Please, read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I've edit question and add an example fiddle. Hope this will explain my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I may have had some bugs in my code. After rewrite and some trials the method of getting coords from intersected plane worked well. Of course with implemented Orbit Controls. This is how my 'onMouseClick' function looks now:

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
   var rect = scope.renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / rect.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / rect.height ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersection = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
  //example box for position visualisation
  box.position.copy(intersection[0].point);
  box.position.y = 0;
```

Three.js r.87